# Block IIS application in Certain Day

Tags: iis, block, days

i need to block the users to access the application host in IIS after certain days?
is there any rule that allow this ?
which mean that the user can access the application for 30 days then it will be blocked automatically
please Help ...
Thanks

Comment: have you done any search at all?

Comment: IIS won't give you that. You need to do it in your web apps yourself.

Comment: @Ibo sure i did, i just to do it through the IIS not coding